# Juego de 3 en línea - Me aparecen duplicado la pregunta

Tags: c++

estoy programando el mítico juego de 3 en línea en C++ mediante consola. Os dejo el código que he usado hasta ahora para que podáis ver los fallos, uno de ellos es que cuando me pide donde quiero poner la ficha me aparece doble o triple y otro fallo es que cuando acabo el tablero y nadie gana no se imprime nada, me sigue pidiendo que introduzca una ficha. Espero ayuda sobre esto, y si veis otro error pues comentármelo. Un saludo

Casi todo es código ya que es muy largo pero he adjuntado comentarios donde explico lo que hace cada función. El tablero se llena con números indicando la posición de la ficha.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

// Declaramos las funciones
void loop (char c[3][3]);
void Intro_Primera (char c[3][3]);
void Intro_Primera (char c[3][3]);
void tablero (char c[3][3]);
void Intro_Yo (char c[3][3]);
void Intro_Otro (char c[3][3]);
int ganador (char c[3][3]);

// Principal
int main () {
    char c[3][3];
    
    loop (c);
    
    //system ("pause");
    return 0;
}

// Loop
void loop (char c[3][3]) {
    int i, j;
    
    i = 0;
    Intro_Primera (c); // Se ejecuta una sola vez la función
    tablero (c); // Se ejecuta una sola vez la función
    
    do {
        system ("clear");
        tablero (c);
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            Intro_Yo (c);
        } else {
            Intro_Otro (c);
        }
        j = ganador (c);
        i++;
        
    } while (i <= 9 && j == 2);
    
    if (j == 0) {
        printf ("ENHORABUENA!!! JUGADOR 1 ha ganado :P \n\n");
    } else if (j == 1) {
        printf ("ENHORABUENA!!! JUGADOR 2 ha ganado :P \n\n");
    } else {
        printf ("OPS! No ha ganado nadie, tocará volver a jugar. \n\n");
    }
}

// Indicamos que llene las posiciones con un espacio vacío
void Intro_Primera (char c[3][3]) {
    char aux;
    aux = '1';
    
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
            c[i][j] = aux++;
        }
    }
}

// Creamos un jugador1
void Intro_Yo (char c[3][3]) {
    char aux;
    int i, j, k;
    
    do {
        do {
            printf ("JUGADOR 1: "); // Pedimos que se ponga una posición donde irá la ficha
            //fflush (stdin);
            scanf ("%c",&aux); // Guardamos dicha posición en aux
        } while (aux < '1' || aux > '9'); // Usamos un while para que cuando la posicion sea menor que 1 o mayor que 9...
        
        k = 0;
        
        switch (aux) { // Con un switch indicamos que pasaía si la posición está ocupada
            case '1': {
                i = 0; // Filas
                j = 0; // Columnas
                if (c[i][j] == 'x' || c[i][j] == 'o'){ // Si en esta posición está alguna de las dos fichas que nos deje vover a indicar otra posición
                    k = 1;
                    printf ("La casilla está ocupada! Indica otra posicion distinta. \n\n");
                }
                break;
            }
            case '2': {
                i = 0; // Filas
                j = 1; // Columnas
                if (c[i][j] == 'x' || c[i][j] == 'o'){ // Si en esta posición está alguna de las dos fichas que nos deje vover a indicar otra posición
                    k = 1;
                    printf ("La casilla está ocupada! Indica otra posicion distinta. \n\n");
                }
                break;
            }
            case '3': {
                i = 0; // Filas
                j = 2; // Columnas
                if (c[i][j] == 'x' || c[i][j] == 'o'){ // Si en esta posición está alguna de las dos fichas que nos deje vover a indicar otra posición
                    k = 1;
                    printf ("La casilla está ocupada! Indica otra posicion distinta. \n\n");
                }
                break;
            }
            case '4': {
                i = 1; // Filas
                j = 0; // Columnas
                if (c[i][j] == 'x' || c[i][j] == 'o'){ // Si en esta posición está alguna de las dos fichas que nos deje vover a indicar otra posición
                    k = 1;
                    printf ("La casilla está ocupada! Indica otra posicion distinta. \n\n");
                }
                break;
            }
            case '5': {
                i = 1; // Filas
                j = 1; // Columnas
                if (c[i][j] == 'x' || c[i][j] == 'o'){ // Si en esta posición está alguna de las dos fichas que nos deje vover a indicar otra posición
                    k = 1;
                    printf ("La casilla está ocupada! Indica otra posicion distinta. \n\n");
                }
                break;
            }
            case '6': {
                i = 1; // Filas
                j = 2; // Columnas
                if (c[i][j] == 'x' || c[i][j] == 'o'){ // Si en esta posición está alguna de las dos fichas que nos deje vover a indicar otra posición
                    k = 1;
                    printf ("La casilla está ocupada! Indica otra posicion distinta. \n\n");
                }
                break;
            }
            case '7': {
                i = 2; // Filas
                j = 0; // Columnas
                if (c[i][j] == 'x' || c[i][j] == 'o'){ // Si en esta posición está alguna de las dos fichas que nos deje vover a indicar otra posición
                    k = 1;
                    printf ("La casilla está ocupada! Indica otra posicion distinta. \n\n");
                }
                break;
            }
            case '8': {
                i = 2; // Filas
                j = 1; // Columnas
                if (c[i][j] == 'x' || c[i][j] == 'o'){ // Si en esta posición está alguna de las dos fichas que nos deje vover a indicar otra posición
                    k = 1;
                    printf ("La casilla está ocupada! Indica otra posicion distinta. \n\n");
                }
                break;
            }
            case '9': {
                i = 2; // Filas
                j = 2; // Columnas
                if (c[i][j] == 'x' || c[i][j] == 'o'){ // Si en esta posición está alguna de las dos fichas que nos deje vover a indicar otra posición
                    k = 1;
                    printf ("La casilla está ocupada! Indica otra posicion distinta. \n\n");
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    } while (k == 1); // Se repetirá siempre que k sea igual a 1
    
    c[i][j] = 'x';
}

// Creamos un jugador2
void Intro_Otro (char c[3][3]) {
    char aux;
    int i, j, k;
    
    do {
        do {
            printf ("JUGADOR 2: "); // Pedimos que se ponga una posición donde irá la ficha
            //fflush (stdin);
            scanf ("%c",&aux); // Guardamos dicha posición en aux
        } while (aux < '1' || aux > '9'); // Usamos un while para que cuando la posicion sea menor que 1 o mayor que 9...
        
        k = 0;
        
        switch (aux) { // Con un switch indicamos que pasaía si la posición está ocupada
            case '1': {
                i = 0; // Filas
                j = 0; // Columnas
                if (c[i][j] == 'x' || c[i][j] == 'o'){ // Si en esta posición está alguna de las dos fichas que nos deje vover a indicar otra posición
                    k = 1;
                    printf ("La casilla está ocupada! Indica otra posicion distinta. \n\n");
                }
                break;
            }
            case '2': {
                i = 0; // Filas
                j = 1; // Columnas
                if (c[i][j] == 'x' || c[i][j] == 'o'){ // Si en esta posición está alguna de las dos fichas que nos deje vover a indicar otra posición
                    k = 1;
                    printf ("La casilla está ocupada! Indica otra posicion distinta. \n\n");
                }
                break;
            }
            case '3': {
                i = 0; // Filas
                j = 2; // Columnas
                if (c[i][j] == 'x' || c[i][j] == 'o'){ // Si en esta posición está alguna de las dos fichas que nos deje vover a indicar otra posición
                    k = 1;
                    printf ("La casilla está ocupada! Indica otra posicion distinta. \n\n");
                }
                break;
            }
            case '4': {
                i = 1; // Filas
                j = 0; // Columnas
                if (c[i][j] == 'x' || c[i][j] == 'o'){ // Si en esta posición está alguna de las dos fichas que nos deje vover a indicar otra posición
                    k = 1;
                    printf ("La casilla está ocupada! Indica otra posicion distinta. \n\n");
                }
                break;
            }
            case '5': {
                i = 1; // Filas
                j = 1; // Columnas
                if (c[i][j] == 'x' || c[i][j] == 'o'){ // Si en esta posición está alguna de las dos fichas que nos deje vover a indicar otra posición
                    k = 1;
                    printf ("La casilla está ocupada! Indica otra posicion distinta. \n\n");
                }
                break;
            }
            case '6': {
                i = 1; // Filas
                j = 2; // Columnas
                if (c[i][j] == 'x' || c[i][j] == 'o'){ // Si en esta posición está alguna de las dos fichas que nos deje vover a indicar otra posición
                    k = 1;
                    printf ("La casilla está ocupada! Indica otra posicion distinta. \n\n");
                }
                break;
            }
            case '7': {
                i = 2; // Filas
                j = 0; // Columnas
                if (c[i][j] == 'x' || c[i][j] == 'o'){ // Si en esta posición está alguna de las dos fichas que nos deje vover a indicar otra posición
                    k = 1;
                    printf ("La casilla está ocupada! Indica otra posicion distinta. \n\n");
                }
                break;
            }
            case '8': {
                i = 2; // Filas
                j = 1; // Columnas
                if (c[i][j] == 'x' || c[i][j] == 'o'){ // Si en esta posición está alguna de las dos fichas que nos deje vover a indicar otra posición
                    k = 1;
                    printf ("La casilla está ocupada! Indica otra posicion distinta. \n\n");
                }
                break;
            }
            case '9': {
                i = 2; // Filas
                j = 2; // Columnas
                if (c[i][j] == 'x' || c[i][j] == 'o'){ // Si en esta posición está alguna de las dos fichas que nos deje vover a indicar otra posición
                    k = 1;
                    printf ("La casilla está ocupada! Indica otra posicion distinta. \n\n");
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    } while (k == 1); // Se repetirá siempre que k sea igual a 1
    
    c[i][j] = 'o';
}

// Imprimimos un tablero vacío
void tablero (char c[3][3]) {
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
            if (j<2){
                printf (" %c |",c[i][j]);
            } else {
                printf (" %c ",c[i][j]);
            }
        }
        if (i<2){
            printf ("\n-----------\n");
        }
    }
    printf ("\n\n");
}

// Indicamos un ganador
int ganador (char c[3][3]) {
    if (c[0][0] == 'x' || c[0][0] == 'o') {
        if (c[0][0] == c[0][1] && c[0][0] == c[0][2]) {
            if (c[0][0] == 'x') {
                return 0; // Jugador 1 ha ganado
            } else {
                return 1; // Jugador 2 ha ganado
            }
        }
        else if (c[0][0] == c[1][0] && c[0][0] == c[2][0]) {
            if (c[0][0] == 'x') {
                return 0; // Jugador 1 ha ganado
            } else {
                return 1; // Jugador 2 ha ganado
            }
        }
    }
    else if (c[1][1] == 'x' || c[1][1] == 'o') {
        if (c[1][1] == c[0][0] && c[1][1] == c[2][2]) {
            if (c[1][1] == 'x') {
                return 0; // Jugador 1 ha ganado
            } else {
                return 1; // Jugador 2 ha ganado
            }
        }
        else if (c[1][1] == c[1][0] && c[1][1] == c[1][2]) {
            if (c[1][1] == 'x') {
                return 0; // Jugador 1 ha ganado
            } else {
                return 1; // Jugador 2 ha ganado
            }
        }
        else if (c[1][1] == c[2][0] && c[1][1] == c[0][2]) {
            if (c[1][1] == 'x') {
                return 0; // Jugador 1 ha ganado
            } else {
                return 1; // Jugador 2 ha ganado
            }
        }
        else if (c[1][1] == c[0][1] && c[1][1] == c[2][1]) {
            if (c[1][1] == 'x') {
                return 0; // Jugador 1 ha ganado
            } else {
                return 1; // Jugador 2 ha ganado
            }
        }
    }
    else if (c[2][2] == 'x' || c[2][2] == 'o') {
        if (c[2][2] == c[2][0] && c[2][2] == c[2][1]) {
            if (c[2][2] == 'x') {
                return 0; // Jugador 1 ha ganado
            } else {
                return 1; // Jugador 2 ha ganado
            }
        }
        else if (c[2][2] == c[0][2] && c[2][2] == c[1][2]) {
            if (c[2][2] == 'x') {
                return 0; // Jugador 1 ha ganado
            } else {
                return 1; // Jugador 2 ha ganado
            }
        }
    }
    return 2;
}
```

Comment: Tengo varias dudas: ¿Por qué declaras dos veces la función Intro_Primera? En la función loop, ¿no inicializas la variable j? Dado el alto grado de similitud entre la función `Intro_Yo` y `Intro_Otro`, ¿por qué no intentas hacer ambas tareas con una sola función?

Comment: Antes de leer las varios decenas de líneas de tu código me gustaría que concretases qué es lo que estás preguntando.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veamos... Expones dos problemas, te intentaré arrojar algo de luz a ambos.

**1. PRIMER PROBLEMA**

> cuando me pide donde quiero poner la ficha me aparece doble o triple

Esto se debe a que en el `scanf()`, cuando se solicita un único carácter normalmente te recoge el salto de línea anterior, y por lo tanto no te reconoce bien el carácter que tú quieres introducir. El tus funciones `Intro_Yo()` y `Intro_Otro()` debes modificar la manera en la que intentas obtener tu variable `aux`. Simplemente inserta un espacio en el argumento de la función. Quedaría de este modo: `scanf (" %c",&aux);`. Fíjate en el espacio que hay entre el primer `"` y el `%c`.

**2. SEGUNDO PROBLEMA**

> cuando acabo el tablero y nadie gana no se imprime nada, me sigue pidiendo que introduzca una ficha.

Cuéntame realmente... ¿Qué esperas obtener? Tienes un bucle `do-while`, cuya condición es `i<=9 && j==2`. Vayamos por partes:

- **i<=9**. Está bastante claro, sólo permites 9 turnos.
- **j==2**. Aquí está el problema. ¿Cuándo va a dejar de valer 2 tu variable `j` en caso de empate? Ya te lo adelanto yo: nunca. En tu función `ganador()` sólo tienes 3 opciones, o que gane el jugador 1 (retorna 0), que gane el jugador 2 (retorna 1), o que nadie gane (retorna 2 ---> por lo tanto `j` vale 2). ¿Cómo quieres que en caso de empate se te salga del bucle `do-while` si tu condición siempre se va a cumplir en caso de empate? Prueba sino a quitar la condición de `j==2` y verás como te funciona al hacer que los jugadores empaten.

**Posible solución**
No la voy a desarrollar porque me llevaría algo de tiempo y mi intención es, como digo al principio, arrojarte algo de luz y que sigas aprendiendo a programar, que lo estás haciendo genial.
Una solución que se me ocurre es que dentro de las funciones `Intro_Yo` e `Intro_Otro` trabajes con variables de retorno que te permitan controlar por dónde llevar el programa. Estas variables de retorno te pueden servir como flags en tu función de `loop` para determinar si has llegado a introducir realmente valores reales. Por ejemplo, que cuando se inserte un valor válido en una casilla libre realmente se incremente tu contador `i` y trabajar de este modo únicamente con la condición de `i<=9` en tu bucle `do-while`. **PD: para esta solución la condición del bucle debe ser `i<9`, si pones el `=` te solicitará un valor de más**

Comment: Solo faltaría mencionar que *printf* y *scanf* son vestigios de C. Por lo que es recomendable usar lo que ofrece la librería estándar: *cout* y *cin*.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón. El código es puramente en C salvo la librería `iostream`. Me he limitado a dar pautas al OP sobre las dudas que ha expuesto, pero como dices, podríamos sacar otras tantas más, como por ejemplo emplear `stdio.h` estando supuestamente en C++, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Primero de todo aprovecho para ofrecerte una [herramienta](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler) que es un "compilador en línea" con debugger para poder ver paso a paso la ejecución de tu código.  Segundo te aconsejo revisar cuantas veces llamas a una función

```
void loop (char c[3][3]) {
    int i, j;
    
    i = 0;
    Intro_Primera (c);
    tablero (c); // AQUÍ LLAMAS A ESTA FUNCIÓN
    
    do {
        system ("clear");
        tablero (c); // AQUÍ OTRA VEZ
```

Y el problema de las múltiples apariciones del "jugador X:" está en el control de las estructuras "do while". Revísalas.